# What is the difference between Fermi level and Fermi edge?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons, terminology, fermions

Just as in title: What is the difference between [Fermi level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level) and [Fermi edge](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Fermi+edge)? My friend makes some research about XPS and he encountered this term. He knows what the Fermi level is, but never heard about Fermi edge.

Comment: I'd say they're the same.  Level is more scientific.  Edge simply sounds like it has a sharper occupation gradient (as if the temperature is low).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know one usually speaks of a *Fermi edge singularity* when referring to a singularity occurring near the Fermi level threshold in a x-ray absorption/emission spectrum of a metal.

Below you will find some useful references:

- One of the first papers on x-ray spectrum singularities for metals: [Singularities in the X-ray absorption and emission of metals. III. One-body theory exact solution by P Nozieres, CT De Dominicis - Physical Review, 1969 - APS](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.178.1097)
- [The Fermi Edge Singularity and Boundary Condition Changing Operators Ian Affleck and Andreas W.W. Ludwig.](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9405057)
- And a brief overview in these slides [here](https://zumbuhllab.unibas.ch/pdf/talks/061218CharulataFermiEdge.pdf).

Comment: The last link is dead now.